# Unit test Fluentvalidation

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have 2 classes as like below

```
public class A
{
   public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class B : A
{
   public string Description { get; set;}
}
```

With the following fluent validators

```
public class AValidator : AbstractValidator<A>
{
   public A()
   {
     RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
   }
}

public class BValidator : AbstractValidator<B>
{
   public B(IValidator<AValidator> aValidator)
   {
     Include(aValidator);
     RuleFor(x => x.Description).NotEmpty();
   }
}
```

I'm using StrctureMap for IOC and xUnit for unit tests. Is there any way that I can validate / verify that Include has been setup in the BValidator?

Comment: `if (aValidator == null) throw new ArgumentException();` ?

Comment: @RomanKoliada if aValidator was null when injected it would throw an exception anyway. I need a way to unit test that any validators for objects that inherit A also Include the the AValidator in their validator.